# Will BigQuery cache the results of nested queries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am generating large nested queries in the form

`Select Col1a,Col2a... 
 From ( Select Col1b,..
       From ( ... Many More Queries Nested ... ))`

with various Joins filters and sorts at each level, and nesting ocuring in the From clause. There is a high likelihood that at some point later in the program some of the inner queries will be run separately. I know BigQuery will cache the results of the outermost queries, however I cannot find any information about caching on the nested query's. Will these results also be cached or is it just the outermost one that gets cached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the outermost query results are cached. Same with views: You could have the inner queries defined as views (the big query will get much simpler that way), but views don't cache results either.

Comment: What if I create temp table of this inner queries (instead of a view). Will it start using cached temp table, when we re-run it immediately?